# Why this program crashes?

Tags: c, crash

This small C program is crashing every single time.

It is supposed to allocate a chunk of memory under the form of a 3D grid composed of many structures (cells) disposed in memory in a 3D-friendly pattern. The structs will be populated with position data.

I don't know why it crashes. It returns this number: c0000005.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct {
int coords[3];
} cell;

int main() {

    int x=4, y=8, z=6;

    int volume=x*y*z;

    cell *arr=(cell*)calloc(volume,sizeof(cell));

    int u=0,v=0,w=0;
    int index;

    for (w=0; w<z; w++) {
    for (v=0; v<y; v++) {
    for (u=0; u<x; u++) {

        //printf("%d %d %d\n", u, v, w);

        index=u+v*y+w*y*z;

        arr[index].coords[0]=u;
        arr[index].coords[1]=v;
        arr[index].coords[2]=w;

        //getchar();

    }}}

    printf("All done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845)

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: You mixed up your dimensions when calculating your index.

Comment: Surely u+v*y+w*y*z becomes greater than x*y*z, so you're indexing into something you've not allocated.

Comment: @Deduplicator If I don't cast the calloc, the comp returns an error that states: "invalid conversion from void* to cell*"

Comment: @nos yep thats it. i now feel dumb...

Comment: @user2464424: Which is a sure indicator that you ain't using a C compiler. I'm guessing you are actually using C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes because i forgot to switch to C when isolating the issue. Im very tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `index=u+v*y+w*y*z;`.

It should be `index=u+v*x+w*y*x;`.

So @nos is right. It triggers a segmentation fault because `6=z>x=4` and `index` becomes too large.